# UIPageControl has unspecified grey background colour

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uipagecontrol

I have a UIPageControl on a UIViewController however despite trying to change the background colour in the attributes inspector it remains this dark grey colour that does not display in the interface builder.

**As shown in the image below:**

[image: Screenshot showing comparison between the simulator and interface builder.]

Any ideas on how I can fix this? - ideally I want a transparent background but I just applied the yellow to compare more clearly.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not editing it somewhere else?

Comment: @EridB I don't think so - it doesn't have an IBOutlet and it's not using a custom class.

Comment: It can be changed also through `UIAppearance` protocol. i.e `UIPageControl.appearance().backgroundColor = .darkGray`. Double check if you call that somewhere in your project.

Comment: @TomFox have you correctly set the `tintColor` and `currentPageIndicatorTintColor` of the `PageControl`?

Comment: @EridB Ah, your right - some code I wrote a while ago. Thanks, I've been puzzling over this for a while!

Comment: @TomFox just posted the comment as an answer below! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the background color of the `UIPageControl` can be done through the `UIAppearance` protocol.

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance)

> You can customize the appearance of instances of a class by sending
>   appearance modification messages to the class’s appearance proxy.

**Example**

```
UIPageControl.appearance().backgroundColor = .darkGray
```

**Solution**

Make sure you do not have a call to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the `tintColor` and `currentPageIndicatorTintColor` of the `UIPageControl`.